# knockout js - partial templates to be more dry

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

New to knockout js.

In a knockout view, say `formtest.html`, is it possible to include a **reusable** partial of html, where the bindings are dynamic ( say passed at the point of the partial template inclusion ?)

---

Say `textarea.html` and the bindings for textarea will be bound to the `ko.observable(`) set in the view model for `formtest.html` ?

Given a viewmodel has

```
this.theviewmodelBinding = ko.observable()
```

and textarea binding would be set like:

```
<textarea data-bind="text: theviewmodelBinding" ...
```

But what if this textarea markup was included as a partial in `formtest.html`, how could the data bind be more dynamic ? Giving the ability to reuse this textarea markup/partial across the web app ?

So,in our textarea.html partial, something say like:

```
<textarea data-bind="text: {{view_model_binding_passedtothispartial}}" ...
```

Is that even possible, is there a short example, and if so what version of knockout is that for ?

No doubt more RTFM needed from me! Sorry if been asked before - Just struggling to find anything related to *"knockout partial bindings for dry templating"*

---

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you go through the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) docs yet? That may be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen I did, looks close, but I couldn't see where it would include the template html /( a partial bit of html ) - it only looked to include the template if it was on the page itself `<script id="templatename">...` ?

Comment: say, hoping something like `<div data-bind='template: { name: partials/textarea.html, .. `

Answer (score 1):

The knockout built-in templating engine does not support this. However, the knockout templating engine is pluggable and there exists at least one (there may be more, just try to search for more if you want to) such templating engine; the Knockout External Template Engine. If you're using nuget, you can easily install [the nuget package for the Knockout External Template Engine](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.js_External_Template_Engine/).

You can find examples on how to use it, as well as some usage instructions at [the Knockout External Template Engine Github page](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine).

Answer (score 1):

I do this by pairing each Knockout template with its very own viewmodel; in my project, I call this combination of template and viewmodel a "card":

```
<div data-bind="card: 'form', cardConfig: {textareaModel: some_observable}"></div>
```

This loads a 'form' Knockout template and binds it to a 'form' viewmodel, which is configured through the `cardConfig` accessor.

The binding looks like this:

```
(function(ko, pica, $) {
  "use strict";

  ko.bindingHandlers.card = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var cardConfig = allBindingsAccessor().cardConfig || {},
          cardName,
          cardVm;

      cardName = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

      // here I find and instantiate the view model belonging to this card
      cardVm = new pica.cards[cardName]();

      // configure it
      cardVm.setup(cardConfig);

      // make sure the Knockout template for this card is present,
      // then render it inside the element the card binding is bound to
      pica.TemplateManager.request(cardName)
        .done(function(templateName) {
          ko.renderTemplate(templateName, cardVm, {}, element);
        });
    }
  };

})(ko, pica, $);
```

The viewmodel for this hypothetical 'form' card would look something like this:

```
(function(pica, ko) {
  "use strict";

  var form;

  form = function form() {
    var that = this;

    this.textarea = ko.observable();

    this.setup = function setup(config) {
      this.textarea( config.textareaModel );
    }
  };

  pica.cards.form = form;

})(window.pica, ko);
```

and its template would simply be

```
<script type="text/html" id="form">
  <!-- our scope is the form viewmodel here -->
  <textarea data-bind="text: textarea"></textarea>
</script>
```